# Ionic list: How to edit the style of the list items?

Tags: ionic-framework

I used the following code inside my side menu:

```
<ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-content>
        <div class="list">
            <a class="item" menu-close href="#/app/products">
                <img src="img/home.png" width="30px" />
                <!-- <i class="icon ion-home"></i> -->
                <h2>YourPhoto24</h2>
            </a>
            <a class="item" menu-close href="#/app/account">
                <img src="img/profile.png" width="30px" />
                <h2>mein Konto</h2>
            </a>
            <a class="item" menu-close href="#/app/orders">
                <img src="img/orders.png" width="30px" />
                <h2>meine Bestellungen</h2>
            </a>
            <a class="item" menu-close href="#/app/receivers">
                <img src="img/receivers.png" width="30px" />
                <h2>meine Empfänger</h2>
            </a>
            <a class="item" menu-close href="#/app/email">
                <img src="img/email.png" width="30px" />
                <h2>Email an uns</h2>
            </a>
            <a class="item" menu-close href="#/app/recommend">
                <img src="img/recommend.png" width="30px" />
                <h2>Empfehlen Sie uns weiter
                    <p>mein Guthaben beträgt zur Zeit: </p>
                </h2>
                
            </a>
            <a class="item" menu-close href="#/app/siteNotice">
                <img src="img/laws.png" width="30px" />
                <h2>AGB &amp; Impressung</h2>
            </a>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-side-menu>
```

So i wanted an icon at the left and the text to the right centered vertically. Unfortunately i did not get the result i expected:

[image]

**1:** How can i manage to get more space between the image and the text and how can i vertically center the text?

**2:** How can i hide the dividers?

**3:** How can i increase the top and bottom padding of the list items? I want them to be 40px.

I added the following to my css file:

```
.menu.menu-left, .list a {
    border-color: transparent;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.menu.menu-left, .list img {
    float: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.menu.menu-left, .list h2 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The padding and the hiding of the divider works with that code. but i cant manage to pretty align the text next to the image centered vertically (both should be centered vertically, the image and the text!)

So whats left is: **How can i manage to get more space between the image and the text and how can i vertically center the text?**

Comment: are you familiar with CSS ? what have you tried ? this is standard CSS behaviour and customization.

Comment: No, im not familiar with CSS. Because of that i thought it would be smart to use the ionic framework. That means i have to change the ionic css files to reach my goals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ionic already provides **a lot** to do something like this with stylings they already made. Take a look at [this example](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#item-icons) in their docs.:

```
<div class="list">
    <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#">
        <i class="icon ion-person"></i>
        mein Konto
    </a>
    <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#">
        <i class="icon ion-navicon-round"></i>
        meine Bestellungen
    </a>
    <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#">
        <i class="icon ion-heart"></i>
        meine Empfänger
    </a>
    <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#">
        <i class="icon ion-email"></i>
        Email an uns
    </a>
    <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#">
        <i class="icon ion-android-share-alt"></i>
        Empfehlen Sie uns weiter 
    </a>
</div>
```

Here is a little codepen to demonstrate what you want:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGBegG

Comment: Yes i know that and i already tried that. The problem is that i do not want to use icons from ionicons. I use my own icons. So i have to use the img tag. and with the img tag it does not work!

Comment: @Mulgard You shouldn't use the image tag, you should rebuild svg-eof-ttf font files with your new icons. It's a bit annoying to do, but it will be easier and cleaner than to re-write custom css IMO. Several solutions to do this are detailled [here](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/add-custom-icons/559/7).

Comment: i read what you posted and for me it is too much hacky... i dont think i want to do that....